# Are the coefficient in a linear combination of eigenstates uniquely determined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

Good evening,

Are the coefficient in a linear combination of eigenstates uniquely determined ? 
Because, for all the exemples I've already seen ( only in 1D ) like the HO, we only determined the complex modulus of this coefficient and then take the only coefficient that was real. 
When we measure the eigenvalue of an operator or when we try to normalize a function, only the complex modulus play a rol so is there a way of finding the phase or can I fix it like I want ?

Thanks for your answers ;)

Comment: Can you give a specific example in more detail?  Since the states form an o.n.b. any state can be expressed as psi = sum(c_n*phi_n), n = ....  For time evolution we choose the energy eigenstates.  So after a measurement of some variable leaves the system in state X, c_n = <X, phi_n>, which is in fact a complex number.

Comment: For example, I must determinate the linear combination of the two first states of the OH that are equally probable and knowing that the average position is zero. I don't know how to find the phase of these states because they cancel everytime i do the integral to average an observable like the position